Deploying Dockerfile to Fly.io does not udpate the actual deployed code
I have a Dockerfile in a monorepo project that I am trying to deploy to Fly.io.
Initial deployment went relatively fine, but now I need to udpate deployed code (add a feature/ fix somnething etc).
Whenever I am happy with local changes, I tried running:

fly deploy
fly deploy --local-only
fly deploy --local-only --no-cache

And every time I go through Docker builds, then I can see in the Fly.io logs that this image is buing pulled but I never get the updated code. My changes remain local and never actually reflected in the deployment.
I don't understand how can one re-deploy something in Fly.io using dockerfile?
What kind of information can I provide to help you help me?

I'm unable to repro you issue. I tried deploying an app to Fly from a Containerfile. Then I updated the app's content, and reran fly deploy, the container was rebuilt, pushed to registry.fly.io and the updated app was deployed. Please provide a minimal repro of your issue in your question. The (sanitized) logs from the deployments would be useful. You should see that the image's sha256 digest changes between builds.

Maybe share your Dockerfile and some info about the app/stack you want to deploy
